# Windows Service cannot connect to web service

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services, windows-services

I have two applications. 1) Windows Form Application 2) Windows Service Application

Both the Form App and the Service App are written in C#, reside on the same PC, and consume the same web service.

The Form App is able to connect to the web service, while the Service App cannot. Why?

The Service App is setup as "local system account".

```
I have already:
  - Turned off the Firewall
  - Disabled all Anti-virus programs
  - Checked folder permissions (both apps are in "\Program Files (x86)\...")
  - Looked at the EventViewer (I saw nothing "strange", although I'm not sure what to look for)
  - Checked the "Allow service to interact with desktop" box in the service properties
```

Another thing to note is that both the Form App and the Service App work an a different PC. This is what led me to investigate folder permissions.

The recorded error within the Service App is: 
10:30:57 {ERROR} WServiceConnector.ServiceConnector.CheckWS [736]- WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server -- StackTrace:    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at PositionWebService.getPositions() in C:\xxxx\xxxx\PositionWebService.cs:line 223
   at WServiceConnector.ServiceConnector.CheckWS(String username, String password) in C:\xxxx\xxxx\ServiceConnector.cs:line 731

Comment: It could be thousands of reasons. Start with checking what kind of exception or error message you are getting. Also try checking network traffic or logs on the web service.

Comment: You've done quite a few checks already. Well done. How did you make sure that the service is app is connecting to the right endpoint (host, port)? What does the error look like? Is this a TCP level error?